# Finding zero of complex function

Tags: equation-solving, complex

Trying to solve $f(z)=\frac{1}{2^z}+\frac{1}{3^z}$. How can I solve it for complex $z$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I solve it for complex z

One way is to use Solve.

```
ClearAll[f,z];
f[z_] := 1/2^z + 1/3^z;
Solve[f[z] == 0, z]

(*Solve::ifun*)
```

> Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not \
>   be found; use Reduce for complete solution information

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
  N[%]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using Reduce gives

```
 Reduce[f[z] == 0, z]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I tried all of these actually, it did not work for me, however I did not put that "Clear" command. Thank you.

Comment: But when I just want to solve f(z)=1 or so, it won't give me anymore the answer! It is weird.

Comment: @HamidEnki it says it can''t solve it in complex domain. But it can in reals. So try `Solve[f[z] == 1, z, Reals]//N` now it works. by default solve works in complex domain. From help, when you add `Reals` then  `solves for real values of variables, but function values are allowed to be complex`

Comment: `Solve[f[z] == 0, z, Method -> Reduce] // Simplify`

Comment: Doesn't work. It works for 0 still.